# Travis CI - android gradle project

Tags: travis-ci

I'm attempting to create a travis build to run this android gradle project.

Travis is erroring on this java related SSL exception. I can't figure out what I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've attached the link to the build, with the full error and build info.

```
$ ./gradlew clean build
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1- all.zip
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:   java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name  matching services.gradle.org found.
at   org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
```

Here is the full build.
[Travis Build](https://travis-ci.org/hartcode/gitcode-for-github)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the cause:

http://discuss.gradle.org/t/urgent-ssl-apache-configuration-for-services-gradle-org-is-bad/8808

Workaround would be to modify `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` with `distributionUrl` using `http` instead of `https`. Until they fix the problem.